# Mixing Generic Programming with Polymorphism

Tags: c++

I have seen a few articles on generic programming and how you should never use virtual functions and templates together. I understand this idiom, as templates are decided at compilation, where virtual functions are not chosen until run-time (over simplification).

However, I have a bit of code that uses OO style and Generic style together and it seems to work the way I want.

My Question:

Is the following design bad practice. Mixing Polymorphism and Generic Code?

Is there any pit falls with my code below. (I know I should not inherit data members, but I have :-/).

```
#ifndef BaseTemplate_H
#define BaseTemplate_H

#include <vector>

template< class T >
class BaseTemplate {

 public:

  typedef std::vector<T*> pVT;

  BaseTemplate(){}
  virtual ~BaseTemplate(){};
  virtual void Process()=0;
  const pVT& getContainer(){ return m_pContainer; }

 protected:

  pVT m_pContainer;

 private:

  BaseTemplate( const BaseTemplate& cpy );
  BaseTemplate& operator=( const BaseTemplate& rhs);



};

#endif
```

I inherit from the base class first by telling the base template what type I would like when inheriting.
This will allow me two inherit for multiple types, which I want to keep separate in my design.

```
#ifndef DerClassA_H
#define DerClassA_H

#include <iostream>
#include "BaseTemplate.h"

class DerClassA: public BaseTemplate<int> {

 public:

 DerClassA(){}
 virtual ~DerClassA(){}
 virtual void Process(){
   std::cout << "HELLO I AM: DerClassA" << std::endl;
 }//This will push_back objects to m_pContainer

 private:

 DerClassA( const DerClassA& cpy );
 DerClassA& operator=( const DerClassA& rhs);



};

#endif


#ifndef DerClassB_H
#define DerClassB_H

#include <iostream>
#include "DerClassA.h"

class DerClassB: public DerClassA {

 public:

 DerClassB(){}
 virtual ~DerClassB(){}
 virtual void Process(){
   std::cout << "HELLO I AM: DerClassB" << std::endl;
 }//This will push_back objects to m_pContainer

 private:

  DerClassB( const DerClassB& cpy );
  DerClassB& operator=( const DerClassB& rhs);



};

#endif

#include "DerClassA.h"
#include "DerClassB.h"

int main()
{

  BaseTemplate<int> *pClassA = new DerClassA();
  pClassA->Process();

  DerClassA *pClassB = new DerClassB();
  pClassB->Process();

  delete pClassA;
  delete pClassB;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A pointer to a vector of pointers and an empty destructor. That's a bigger issue, IMO.

Comment: @jrok Woops Copy and paste out of actual code failed. I will edit. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the following design bad practice. Mixing Polymorphism and Generic Code?

No, that's sometimes the right thing to do.

> Is there any pit falls with my code below.

- The container with raw pointers `std::vector<T*> pVT;` looks a bit fishy.
- The base class destructor should probably be pure virtual.
- I would use the C++11 syntax for making the class non-copyable.
- You only need to make the base class non-copyable.
- I don't see the need for dynamic allocation in your main function.

For the rest I don't see any immediate errors.

It's not possible to say whether or not your design is good without knowing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes I a raw pointer is not what I would implement if I had a choice for a code review of the actual code. shared pointer would suit my design here. In regards to the C++11 I am not aware of this. Any good references? Also my package has to work with Scientific linux so my gcc compiler is dated to say the least (that's another problem though).

Comment: @MWright [This](http://ideone.com/7Sux5) is what the code looks like after some cleaning up and with annotations.

Comment: Thanks some nice new c++11. I'll look into this. One comment though - in main. You are not using polymorphism, which was the whole point of my question, but it doesn't change anything in this example I know :-D

Comment: There's no reason to make the base class destructor pure virtual. The class is already abstract, so the inconvenience of having to define the destructor outside the class wouldn't bring any benefit. (It does need to be virtual, just not pure).